# Mispronunciation of "entrepreneur"

Tags: pronunciation

In the last few years, a new pronunciation (or if you like a mispronunciation) of "entrepreneur" has spread like Covid-19 through the USA, so that even educated speakers, such as NPR reporters, are suddenly pronouncing "entrepreneur" to rhyme with "sewer", "fewer", or "manure".

None of these cultural influencers seems to notice that the "e" precedes the "u", or be aware that the French word has the "eur" ending that rhymes with "purr", "her", or "restaurateur".

This grates on my reactionary language instincts, especially since I am an entrepreneur by trade.

Does anyone know how or where this new phenomenon gained so much momentum? Are there other words changing like this?

Comment: Tomato, tomato.

Comment: Not a real question.

Comment: @GEdgar The question underlying the peeve is a very real and interesting one. If in fact the suggested change is the case, what local dialects is it most common in, is it a sign of a more general phenomenon (and what are the parameters of that rule)?

Comment: Steve, can you find a youtube clip or some other recording where you hear this, so that we can confirm the sound?

Comment: This has been a working class (or supposedly working class) pronunciation in the UK for time out of mind. I actually think that is more of a joke than a genuine piece of working class dialect but it has been around all my 70 years. Perhaps some Americans have picked it up not realising that it was a joke.

Comment: I can understand your irritation at being rhymed with "manure" however this mangling of French has history. I refer you to the various US pronunciations that can be heard here - I find the third one "chase lounge" laughable. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/american_english/chaise-longue

Comment: None of sewer, fewer, and manure rhyme in my dialect.  *Manure*  does rhyme with *entrepreneur.* MW confirms identical pronunciations of final syllable.

Comment: It grates on my nerves too, as I am a French speaker, but I can tell you that it's far from new. I've been hearing it my whole life. Native English-speakers on both sides of the Atlantic seem to have a penchant for butchering French. I remember hearing people in sitcoms when I was a child talking about _ordoovers_ when they were asking for _hors- d'oeuvres_. There are so many examples.

Answer (score 6):

That’s just a regular pronunciation of the spelling “-neur” in English. The word “[amateur](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=amateur)” also has variant pronunciations with the vowel of “cure”/“manure”. (By that I mean an r-controlled “long u” sound, where the influence of the following r has caused the vowel to sound like the lax “oo” of “book” for some speakers. Other speakers have merged the “cure” vowel into either the “nurse” vowel or the “north”/“force” vowel.)

French doesn’t actually have exactly the same vowel here as in English “purr”. It’s close or approximately equivalent, but neither English pronunciation is actually “correct” if your standard is native French speakers’ pronunciation.

If that isn’t your standard, I think it’s somewhat arbitrary to prefer one anglicized pronunciation over another.